# Find Theta Class of T(n) = T(3n/4) + T(n/6) +5n

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science

I'm not quite sure I can apply the Master Theorem to T(n) = T(3n/4) + T(n/6) + 5n.
It is not in the normal form of T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n). Is it possible to apply the MT to it? If not, can the recurrence be resolved without using Akra Bazzi?

Comment: Actually I was hoping to solve this without the Akra–Bazzi method (if possible).